# How JavaScript code execution order works?

Tags: javascript, fifo, lifo

When i used setInterval i encountered a problem, order of executing code suprised me:

```
var attack1 = setInterval(function(){
        weapon1.style.visibility = "visable";
        weapon1.animate(attack1Animation, attackTiming);
        weapon1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 10000/unit1.attack_speed);
```

weapon1.style.visibility = "hidden";
is executing faster than
weapon1.animate(attack1Animation, attackTiming);

I know we have LIFO and FIFO in JS. Asynchronus JS and functions (i am not sure if all kind of functions) execute after other code. So i tried something like this:

```
function notVisable() {
        weapon1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    var attack1 = setInterval(function(){
        weapon1.style.visibility = "visable";
        weapon1.animate(attack1Animation, attackTiming);
        notVisable();
    }, 10000/unit1.attack_speed);
```

without those 2 lines everything is still working:

- weapon1.style.visibility = "visable";
- weapon1.style.height = "200px";

Animation works, so it's not fault of the animation.

Probably i would somehow manage to fix it, but i want to unterstand how it works :D

Comment: The css `visibility` property should be `visible` not `visable`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Comment: Also, as per your central issue, I think your `visibility = hidden` is executing while the animation is still running. So, technically, your animation is running fine but is invisible.

Comment: the problem here is not execution order, the problem is that the animate function starts the animation but the execution won't wait until it's finished and will continue to execute other code as the animation goes.

Comment: A possible fix would be to remove the code setting visibility and instead set the opacity in the animation, i.e., opacity: 0 (hidden) and  opacity: 1 (visible)

Comment: hmmmm, i was thinking about setTimeout, but i will for sure check your idea, maybe it will works better :D

Comment: Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wu9431cv/show) using opacity to show the weapon animation.  See this [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats) for more information.